# Как не удалить дубли, а лишь отметить их (важно чтобы первый был отмечен единицей)?

Tags: python, csv

На входе есть данные в формате csv типа:

```
id,zver,St2,St3
1,Ежик,вафыа,аппав
2,Лошадка,фафа,яфавв
3,Заяц,аппфпа,фываф
4,Ежик,фывафва,павфа
5,Медвед,фафаф,ывафыва
6,Лиса,фываф,фафенен
7,Ежик,тист,ароао
8,Крот ,аарпо,роарпо
9,Лошадка,впрвар,рврвапр
```

Все решения, которые нахожу построены по принципу удалить дубли, а мне нужно не удалить их, а только отметить как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Важно. В таблице много столбцов и надо находить дубли только по одному из столбцов.

Где вообще в питоне лежит это решение?

Comment: Например, хранить индексы дублей

Comment: В чем разница между "так" и "или так"?

Comment: Сорри, поправил.

Comment: Эта задача легко (1-2 строчки кода) решается при использовании [модуля Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). Могу показать решение если вы опубликуете пример CSV файла в виде текста (так чтобы его можно было скопировать)

Comment: id,zver,St2,St3
1,Ежик,вафыа,аппав
2,Лошадка,фафа,яфавв
3,Заяц,аппфпа,фываф
4,Ежик,фывафва,павфа
5,Медвед,фафаф,ывафыва
6,Лиса,фываф,фафенен
7,Ежик,тист,ароао
8,Крот ,аарпо,роарпо
9,Лошадка,впрвар,рврвапр

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(filename)

mask = df.groupby('zver')['zver'].transform('size') == 1
df['dubl'] = np.where(mask, 0, df.groupby('zver').cumcount()+1)
df.to_csv(r'c:/temp/out.csv', index=False)
```

Результат:

```
id,zver,St2,St3,dubl
1,Ежик,вафыа,аппав,1
2,Лошадка,фафа,яфавв,1
3,Заяц,аппфпа,фываф,0
4,Ежик,фывафва,павфа,2
5,Медвед,фафаф,ывафыва,0
6,Лиса,фываф,фафенен,0
7,Ежик,тист,ароао,3
8,Крот ,аарпо,роарпо,0
9,Лошадка,впрвар,рврвапр,2
```

Результат в виде Pandas DataFrame (в табличном виде):

```
In [190]: df
Out[190]:
   id     zver      St2      St3  dubl
0   1     Ежик    вафыа    аппав     1
1   2  Лошадка     фафа    яфавв     1
2   3     Заяц   аппфпа    фываф     0
3   4     Ежик  фывафва    павфа     2
4   5   Медвед    фафаф  ывафыва     0
5   6     Лиса    фываф  фафенен     0
6   7     Ежик     тист    ароао     3
7   8    Крот     аарпо   роарпо     0
8   9  Лошадка   впрвар  рврвапр     2
```

Comment: Спасибо, но. здесь идет подсчет количества, а мне нужно отметить именно дубли. Если дублей нет, то значение dubl должно быть 0 или просто отсутствовать.

Comment: @Валери, мне эта логика не очень понятна, но сделал так как вы хотели... ;)

Comment: Супер. Спасибо огромное!!!